# understanding wildcard in solr

Tags: search, solr

What is the difference between

```
q=have
```

and

```
q=*have*
```

(Same amount of rows are returned)

1. when retrieving the following line "We have located the ship." the score is 1 when using wild card and 1.7437795 whithout.
2. Does it use inflections (having,had,has)

Thank you.

Comment: Are you using some kind of `stemming` on the field?

Answer (score 3):

> Range queries [a TO z], prefix queries a*, and wildcard queries a*b
>   are constant-scoring (all matching documents get an equal score). The
>   scoring factors tf, idf, index boost, and coord are not used. There is
>   no limitation on the number of terms that match (as there was in past
>   versions of Lucene).

So if you have a wildcard query

1. The Scores would always be the same for all the results
2. Wildcard queries do not undergo any analysis
3. Also, *have* wildcard queries would match the any term having have as its content. Basically it is a prefix query that means start with and wildcard query.

Answer (score 0):

```
q=*have*
```

does not work if you don't have a reverseWilcard filter.
Iøm just speculationg because I donøt know your schema but your field it is probably taking your star at the beginning as an extra char in the search term therefore giving it a lesser score than the exact word.